# Python 3 operator.div?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a slight problem with randomly generated operators in Python 3.

```
import operator
hardOperators = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul]
random_hardOperator = random.choice(hardOperators)
```

So you see, I have the operator functions `add`, `sub` and `mul`.
But when I try and add the `div` operator I get an alert saying that `operator has no attribute 'div'`.

I've never actually tried using random operators in Python before, so this might sound a foolish question, but it's one which is giving me hell in debugging.

Comment: This would have been easily answered by checking the documentation for the `operator` module.

Comment: You should read the documentation for `operator`, where you will see there is no `operator.div`. Actually, you should always consult the documentation first, especially when things don't work like you expect :)

Comment: @DavidZ: so what if the OP is accidentally looking at the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.div)?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: but there [is such an attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.div), in *Python 2*. Easy mistake to make, really.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters.  I don't think this is a bad question.  I'm actually _really_ surprised that `operator.div` isn't in python3.x (I'd expect it to do the same thing as `operator.truediv` -- Though I understand the reasoning for the change).

Comment: @mgilson: my guess is that that was omitted to make it clear when porting. I still would like to see a future version of Python 3 (one that drops `u'..'` prefix support perhaps) to add that alias..

Comment: @MartijnPieters They already had one or two that dropped `u'...'` prefixing ;-).  But I agree.  I'm looking forward to the day when python3.x use dwarfs python2.x use so that backward compatibility and porting issues aren't as relevant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (5 comments up) then the OP would be looking at the wrong documentation. Surely it should come as no surprise that looking at the wrong documentation is likely to give the wrong information. Now, if the question had been along the lines of "the documentation says there is an `operator.div` but it doesn't exist in the interpreter", I wouldn't complain about that, or "the documentation doesn't explain why there is no `operator.div` in Python 3", I wouldn't complain about that either. But I don't think it's too much to expect to _look_ at the documentation.

Comment: @DavidZ: or the wrong tutorial. Or the wrong codebase. That doesn't change that this is not *confusing* and will trip up some people not familiar yet with the Python 2 to 3 transition. Just like `print item` vs `print(item)`. Or unicode, str, and bytes. Or `urllib2` vs. `urllib.request`. Etc. etc. etc. If you are starting with Python and the version divide is new to you, the documentation will *not necessarily be of much help*.

Answer (score 15):

There is no `operator.div` in Python 3, no; that only existed in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.div).

There is a [`operator.truediv()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv) instead, as well as a [`operator.floordiv()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv). The reason for this division (no pun intended) is that the old Python 2 `/` operator would return an integer if both operands are integers, a float otherwise, while these two functions always return the same type, regardless of the type of inputs.